# Writing jquery function in head is not called

Tags: jquery

I have copied the same example form [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/change/) website to implement the functionality of `change()` in jQuery. If the `<script>..</script>` is cut and pasted in head part, then the function is not at all called on changing the select value. Is there any reason I should write this fragment below select? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/95kKP/) is the fiddle in which I placed the `<script>` part in the header. The default code is [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/8MQwR/).

Comment: you have to load the JS after the DOM is loaded, and you don't show your code, so...what's the code look like?

Comment: Posting a fiddle in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding the function (while still in head) with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   //Your code here

});
```

Comment: I had to bind the elements. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that your DOM is not ready. When working with the DOM inside jQuery, you should bind the `document` element's [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // execute your code here.
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the shortcut function as follows:

```
$(function() {  

});
```

For your example, the updating your code in the `head` as follows should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $('#select_id').change(function() {  
        // handle the change event
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to select one of the answers if they were helpful.

Comment: Hmm.. I will accept an answer for sure. I will do it in next 4 to 5 hours if I don't get any answer. If I will accept an answer now then people will be less interested to give another alternative. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Huh? There are no other alternatives ;) These are the correct answers to your question...

Comment: Ok. I have accepted the fist solution which I got from @Kevin Browserx

Comment: @BenM any help for my code => paste.ofcode.org/kRj8Eac3U26ikTTLePeCwL

Answer (score 1):

If you put the script in the head block, then the page may not have finished loading before it is executed. jquery has a mechanism to deal with this, which is to run script when the document is ready. This is done as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.target').change(function() {  alert('Handler for .change() called.');});

});
```

Any code inside the ready function will be called once the document is fully loaded. Almost all my jquery code gets called this way.